# How to use one scp command to copy specified files from local to server, for total different directories?

Tags: scp

I want to copy this:

```
Local > Remote |
/home/jack/file1.txt > /usr/local/web/jack_files/file1.txt
/home/jason/file2.txt > /usr/local/web/jasonfile/file2.txt
/home/jones/folder/file3.txt > /usr/local/web/jones/folder2/file3.txt
```

They are from totally different places on local and to totally different paths on server.

I want to use only one scp command, is it possible?

fyi, I want to use only one command is because I don't want to authenticate more than once.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to send to multiple remote locations with a single scp command. It can accommodate multiple source files but only one destination. Using SCP command it must run twice.

```
scp file1 file2 root@remote:/location1 
scp file1 file2 root@remote:/location2
```

Best you can do is copy multiple files at same remote location. And then move them to required location (Although it will require authentication).

Comment: I think the copy first move then solution is also working. thanks!